# Problem setting UIImageView Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to set my imageview:

```
detailedEventViewController.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"amnesia.png"];
```

but get the error:

```
2011-01-08 09:53:24.153 HD Pocket Vacations[24697:207] -[DetailedEventViewController thumbnail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x624d820
2011-01-08 09:53:24.247 HD Pocket Vacations[24697:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailedEventViewController thumbnail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x624d820'
```

My outlets are wired up correctly.

Comment: So there's definitely a "thumbnail" property that's an UIImageView which has been synthesized?

Comment: oh jeez. i forgot to synthesize it. you should post that as an answer so i can give you credit...

Comment: I've posted what is hopefully a useful generic answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with your "thumbnail" property.

As such, you'll need to check:

1. Whether it's been correctly defined and synthesized within your interface and implementation file(s).
2. Whether it's an UIImageView.
3. The spelling on all of the above.