# UIImageView doesn't update with my image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to set my image:

```
detailedEventViewController.thumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"amnesia.png"];
```

But the imageview appears blank. amnesia.png is in my resources group. The file exists.

Results of my log:

```
2011-01-08 10:52:32.822 HD Pocket Vacations[25271:207] Image: <UIImage: 0x66203b0>
2011-01-08 10:52:32.823 HD Pocket Vacations[25271:207] dEVC: <DetailedEventViewController: 0x6628340>
2011-01-08 10:52:32.824 HD Pocket Vacations[25271:207] thumbnail: (null)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem setting UIImageView Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634977/problem-setting-uiimageview-image)

Comment: mis-spelling *two* tags, when you have auto-complete, takes some doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you link up the `thumbnail` property to a `UIImageView` in IB?

Try to get a little more information by changing the line to:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"amnesia.png"];
NSLog(@"Image: %@",img);
NSLog(@"dEVC: %@",detailedEventViewController);
NSLog(@"thumbnail: %@",detailedEventViewController.thumbnail);

detailedEventViewController.thumbnail.image = img;
```

and tell what you see in the debugger console window.

Comment: yes it is wired up in IB, thumbnail is connected to files owner

Comment: I added some instructions on how to get some debugging information out of it.

Comment: It's right there: `thumbnail: (null)`. So you either didn't wire it up correctly, didn't load the nib at all, or set `thumnail` to `nil` somewhere.

Comment: I am calling this right after I alloc init detailedEventViewController. I basically have a view controller that is pushing detailedEventViewController onto the navigation stack, and I want the image to be loaded once this happens.

Comment: Do you alloc/init only? You should alloc/initWithNibName, or the nib will not load!

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the logs you provided. When are you attempting to set this? If you are trying to do this in your init method it won't have bound to the Nib yet and why it is Null.

Do this in the `viewDidLoad:` method and it should have hooked up.

Comment: i am doing this in the view controller that is pushing this view controller onto the nav stack.

Comment: Exactly. There is no guarantee that your Nib has been loaded at that point. Its lazy so the nib only loads late. Possibly try setting it in the nav controllers delegate.  UINavigationControllerDelegate method navigationController:didShowViewController:animated: